# Tests passed in VS, but failed in Jenkins, which cannot recognize German letters

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, easyrepro

In my tests I use locators with German letters, for example, `.//button[@aria-label='Löschen']`.

These tests successfully passed in Visual Studio, but failed while executed in Jenkins with such an exception

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//button[@aria-label='L”schen']"}
```

In folder where repo is downloaded all there letters are correct.

So looks like either during build (use MSBuild .NET 4 option in Jenkins job) or during execution (use Jenkins Batch command `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe`) German-specific letters are lost and cannot be recognized.

May be there is kind of plugin or so one for Jenkins to fix this?

Searched for 'German' in available Jenkins plugins, but results are empty. 'Locale' plugin seems to be only for interface language change.

Comment: What is the culture of the system VS runs on and what is the culture of the Jenkins Build System? If you use coded tests you might simply want to switch current culture in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Unicode instead of plaintext Umlauts in your code, that's how I solved this particular issue in my Selenium Smoketests running inside Jenkins (with Junit5 on a Java 17 codebase)

```
„ä“ (U+00E4) \u00E4
„ü“ (U+00FC) \u00FC
„ö“ (U+00F6) \u00F6
„Ä“ (U+00C4) \u00C4
„Ü“ (U+00DC) \u00DC
„Ö“ (U+00D6) \u00D6
```

So in your example it'd be

```
.//button[@aria-label='L\u00F6schen']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem was in Chrome browser headless mode. Due to very complicated structure of document some locators were unable to found in headless mode, but after turning it off all started to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).